# PHP syntax highlighting through SSH from Mac OS X

Tags: vim, ssh, syntax-highlighting, osx-leopard

I connect to my server through SSH in `Terminal.app` to use Vim to edit PHP scripts.

I have install some plugins, including [php.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1571) and another [php.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2874) but it doesn't show me anything! So how can I enable highlighting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need these plugins.

Just type `:syntax on` in *normal* mode or add `syntax on` to `~/.vimrc` on the server.

Assuming, of course, that you run a reasonably recent version of Vim on a UNIX-y server.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for those plug-ins, simply put the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
syntax on
```

To debug further, you need to ensure you have the following `set` once you open a PHP file:

```
syntax=php
filetype=php
```

You can check these like so:

```
:verbose set syntax? filetype?
```

You should see something like this:

```
  syntax=php
        Last set from /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syntax.vim
  filetype=php
        Last set from /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim
```

If syntax highlighting isn't working for other file-types, check the values of:

```
:echo $TERM 
:echo $TERMCAP
:echo &t_Co
```

To ensure you're using a terminal type that allows colour.